# CamelProxy & @Produce - multiple URIs from same POJO

Tags: java, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I've been reading the camel documentation and looking for samples regarding [CamelProxy](http://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html) and [`@Produce`](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html), trying to figure if it possible to produce payloads for multiple routes from the same proxy.

To get a better grasp of the concept, let's suppose we have the following interface:

```
public interface UserServiceTransport {
    void save(User user);
    User load(String userId);
}
```

Would it be possible have a proxy injected in a POJO, and calling one the 2 methods would kick-start the appropriate route?

Perhaps I've missed or misunderstood something from the docs... I'm trying to reuse some legacy code in a new application, and all the samples I've seen so far either have interfaces with 1 method or more overloaded methods, eg:

```
public class UserService {
    @Produce(uri = "direct:save_user")
    protected UserServiceTransport transport;

    public void save(User user) {
        transport.save(user)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not helpful in my case because I'd have to create many interfaces and classes.

Alternatively, is there any other way I can call a few routes from a POJO?